# Can abstract algebra be used to prove points are constructible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing a self-study of abstract algebra, and have a basic question:

Using field extensions, abstract algebra can clearly be used to prove certain points are not constructible (with compass and straight edge).  But, can algebra be used to prove points are constructible with the same instruments?

Comment: Here is an example where algebra provides a proof of constructibility. Suppose $N=2^{w}+1$ is prime. (For $w\gt 0$, this can only happen if $w=2^n$ for some $n\ge 0$.) Then the field obtained by adding a non-trivial $N$-th root of unity to the rationals is of degree $2^w$ over the rationals, so can be reached by a sequence of quadratic extensions. It follows that the $N$-th root of unity is constructible, and therefore so is the regular $N$-gon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. Once you've proven that a point is constructible *only if* its coordinates can be obtained by sequences of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q$, then you need to prove that any element of any such extension can actually be constructed, turning your "only if" into an "if and only if". In order to do this, we need to provide explicit steps to construct such a point, thus we do need to step outside of algebra and use classical geometry, but that's not really surprising.

Once one has proven that $(x, y)$ is constructible iff $(x, 0)$ and $(y, 0)$ are, the usual way is to find explicit geometric constructions to construct:

1. $(a + b, 0)$ from $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 0)$.
2. $(a - b, 0)$ from $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 0)$.
3. $(ab, 0)$ from $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 0)$.
4. $(a/b, 0)$ from $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 0)$.
5. $(\sqrt a, 0)$ from $(a, 0)$.

Points 1 through 4 show that if we can construct any element of a field, we can construct the whole field. Since quadratic extensions are always obtained by adjoining square roots, point 5 shows that we can obtain any quadratic extension we like. Thus all points covered by our "only if" criterion are actually constructible.

Points 1 and 2 are easy using a few compass strokes. 3 and 4 are more complex, making use of the concept of similar triangles. Point 5 is an application of the Pythagorean theorem.

Thus, for example, I can conclude that the point $(1+\sqrt {2 - \sqrt 6}, \frac {1 + \sqrt 5} 2)$ is constructible.

Comment: Don't we still have to prove that any point that is not impossible to construct, is in fact possible to construct?

Comment: @user54301 That's exactly what I said in my answer.

Comment: Let me rephrase - where have we proven that there cannot exist an x that belongs to a field with degree equal to a power of 2, which we cannot construct via the methods you've explained ?  We may not know what that point is, but that does mean it does not exist.  (I realize this is not exactly the same as my original question.)

Comment: @user54301 Oh, you're thinking of a slightly different necessary condition than I was. You need a stronger necessary condition than "A point is constructible only if it's in an extension of degree $2^n$". Namely, you need the condition "A point is constructible only if it's in a tower of extensions, each extension of which is of degree $2$". This doesn't require a more complicated proof than for the weaker condition. In fact, all the proofs I know prove the stronger condition *first*, but then reformulate it as the weaker condition because it's simpler.